# Django: Cannot assign "<Profile: Profile object (None)>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a signup form using Django. I'm getting this error while submitting the form.

Here's what I've done.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_ID  = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar      = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/',     default='img/none/default-avatar.png')

def updateUserProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

post_save.connect(updateUserProfile, dispatch_uid="app_models_updateUserProfile")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
# Create your views here.

class SignUpView(View):
    templateName = 'auth/signup.html'

    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, self.templateName, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        return render(request, self.templateName, {'form': form})
```

From the error traceback, I can see that the error is because of the fact that somehow two signup requests are being sent at a time.
It shouldn't happen 'cause I've used this,

```
post_save.connect(updateUserProfile, dispatch_uid="app_models_updateUserProfile")
```

Here's the traceback,

[Error traceback #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUM3I.png)

[Error traceback #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHr3g.png)

I guess I've done something silly. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've connected your signal handler to *all* post-save signals. So when you call `instance.profile.save()`, it's called again on the profile itself, which it then tries to assign as the user attribute in another newly-created Profile.

You should restrict it to only be called on post-save for User:

```
post_save.connect(updateUserProfile, sender=User, ...)
```

(Not sure why you've specified the dispatch_uid; you normally don't need that.)

Comment: So if I don't specify any sender, every action that saves a models instance will call the post_save signal?

Comment: I've used dispatch_uid just to prevent multiple signals to occur. I thought that would work fine. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Comment: Sorry for going off topic, but that ended up to another error UNIQUE constraint failed: app_profile.user_id. Should I be doing something else as well?

Comment: You might have invalid data in your db now due to the previous attempts.